# R How to construct polynom with form c0 + c1 * x + .. + cn * x^n from orthogonal lm (with poly(raw=F))

Tags: r, lm, poly

How can I extract the coefficients of an orthogonal polynomial regression in R?

It works like a charm with a raw regression:

```
#create datas
set.seed(120)
x= 1:20
y=x^2 + rnorm(length(x),0,10)
datas = data.frame(x,y)

#compute raw model with function poly
mod= lm(data=datas, y~poly(x,2,raw=T))

#get coefficients with function coef()
coefficients = coef(mod)

#construct polynom and check fitted values
fitted_values = mod$fitted.values
x0 = datas$x[1]
solution = coefficients[1]+ coefficients[2]*x0^1 + coefficients[3]*x0^2
print(solution)
# 1.001596 
print(fitted_values[1])
# 1.001596
# 1.001596  == 1.001596
```

But the coefficient obtained  with the function `coef` on an orthogonal lm does not work:

```
#create datas
set.seed(120)
x= 1:20
y=x^2 + rnorm(length(x),0,10)
datas = data.frame(x,y)

#compute raw model with function poly
mod = lm(data=datas, y~poly(x,2,raw=F))

#get coefficients with function coef()
coefficients = coef(mod)
fitted_values = mod$fitted.values

#construct polynom and check fitted values
x0 = datas$x[1]
solution = coefficients[1]+ coefficients[2]*x0^1 + coefficients[3]*x0^2
print(solution)
# 805.8476 
print(fitted_values[1])
# 1.001596
# 1.001596 != 805.8476
```

Is there another way to get the right parameters to construct a polynom of the form c0 + c1 * x + .. + cn * x^n and use it to solve or predict?

I need to solve the equation, meaning getting the x given a y with the function  `base::solve`.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you don't only need the coefficients but also the orthogonal polynomials (instead of the raw polynomials you are trying to use). The latter are constructed by `model.matrix`:

```
newdata <- model.matrix(~ poly(x, 2), data = datas)
solution <- newdata %*% coefficients
print(solution[1])
# [1] 1.001596 
print(fitted_values[1])
#1.001596
```

I don't understand the connection to `solve` but trust you can take it from here.

Comment: I need to solve f(x) = 1.001596 and find x=1 with the model of my example. Sometimes the raw  regression gives NA for the x^2 coefficient while the orthogonal regression works. But i can't solve an orthogonal regression with the base::solve() function.

Comment: Why are you using `solve` for this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Solving_the_quadratic_equation

Comment: I used ```solve``` because it works with a list of non-orthogonal polynomial coefficient but does not fit for orthogonal polynomial. I either need to find the corresponding raw polynom of an orthogonal polynom or find a way to solve f(x) = y with an orthogonal polynom.

Comment: Maybe i'm just missing the mathematical way do to so. I'm gonna check your link

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing with `solve`. I don't see how you are deriving `x` for a given `y` from it. It solves `a %*% x = b` for x. But we have `X %*% beta = y`

Comment: Here is how i used ```solve``` when I could retrieve coefficients:```polyn=polynom::polynomial(c(0,0,1))``` creates the x^2 polynome object. Then ```solve(polyn,1)``` solve the equation x^2 = 1 and return -1 et 1. But if i can solve an orthogonal polynom without ```solve``` that's fine too. I was not used to matrix multiplication operators in R, maybe that's what I'm missing here.

Comment: I still don't get it. Are you not doing linear regression? Linear regression would solve `X %*% beta = y` for beta if there was no uncertainty. Since there is uncertainty, it minimizes `sum((X %*% beta - y) ^ 2)`. What do you need `solve` for if you do regression?

Comment: Sorry I might not be clear enough i my question i did not want to over explain, i'm doing for example a regression on a dataset that has a range of x = [10,20] and a range of y = [100,200]. I obtain a linear model which is an orthogonal polynomial regression, my question is "given the lm I just obtained, which is an orthogonal polynomial of degree 2 or more, what x gives me y=350 ?". ```solve``` did the job for a raw polynom, but not for an orthogonal polynom. I wrote a dichotomic function in R to find the solutions but it's slow and there is probably another faster way that I don't know.

Comment: Would a numeric approach be sufficient? `uniroot(function(x) predict(mod, newdata = list(x = x)) - y, c(0, 100))` This finds only one root and, as you know, there are usually two. Adjust the interval to find both. A plot is useful for this.